# VaR (value-at-risk) of a Normal Random Variable - Confused about Scaling in Derivation

Tags: normal-distribution, standardization, risk

In the book "Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools - Revised Edition" (by McNeil, Frey, and Embrechts)", there is the following example (example 2.11):

> Suppose that the loss distribution $F_L$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and
> variance $\sigma^2$. Fix $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then
>
> $$ VaR_\alpha = \mu + \sigma \Phi (\alpha) $$ where $\Phi$ denotes the
> standard normal df (distribution function) and $\phi^{-1}(\alpha)$ is
> the $\alpha$-quantile of $\Phi$.

The definition of $VaR_\alpha$ is given in the first line below.

So my steps were
[image]

Now I just need to show that $F_\frac{L-\mu}{\sigma}^{-1}(\alpha) = \Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$, but I don't understand why exactly they would be equal. Scaling $L$ to $\frac{L-\mu}{\sigma}$ would shift the mean and change the variance to that of the standard normal, but wouldn't the normalization constant still be off, even after scaling $F_L$ or $L$?

Comment: Your argument seems perfectly fine. What exactly do you mean by the normalization constant being off?

Comment: Why are your steps presented as an image?